# Schema comparison in VS2012

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, schema-compare

In VS2012 I have two SQL Server projects imported from Scripts (*.sql). Is it possible to compare these two schemes and generate SQL script for the differences?

Comment: yes it is possiable ,as I know there is a extention for vs 2010 compare schema.

Comment: http://www.dzone.com/articles/visual-studio-2012-schema-0

Comment: I know about this extension and I actually use it but it works only when you import projects directly from SQL Server. But if you import it from Scripts, as I did, it doesn't allow to generate the script for differences...